# HTTP Record/Playback alternatives to Eclipse+Solex

Tags: linux, eclipse, http, testing, automated-tests

I have been playing with Solex, http://solex.sourceforge.net/ ... quite a cool Eclipse plugin that allows you to record and playback HTTP traffic, make assertions, request-time header mods based on variables pulled from prior requests (via regexp, XPath).

All in all, quite impressed; **However**, I can not see any method for runtime mutation of a URL (as opposed to a GET or POST argument). A limitation as all my URLs are pretty.

Been Google-ing but came up dry on alternatives. Do you guys know any similar systems for Eclipse/Linux? Ideally with a similar 'find X in request `n` use in request `n+1` for uids and the such.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody mentioned Selenium RC and Selenium IDE ... shame. Now I have to answer my own question.

**Links**:

1. http://seleniumhq.org/
2. http://cubictest.openqa.org/